# What is wrong with this MySQL UPDATE syntax?

Tags: mysql

```
SET @currentID = (SELECT MIN(ExperimentID) FROM Jobs_t WHERE JobStatus = 'ToRun');
UPDATE [Jobs_t]
SET [JobStatus] = 'Pending'
WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID;
SELECT @currentID
```

Jobs_t is a table with two columns, ExperimentID and JobStatus. My SQL syntax is wrong on line 2, `UPDATE [Jobs_t]`, but I can't seem to find out why.

I updated the syntax to:

```
SET @currentID = (SELECT MIN(`ExperimentID`) FROM `Jobs_t` WHERE `JobStatus` = 'ToRun');
UPDATE `Jobs_t`
SET `JobStatus` = 'Pending'
WHERE `ExperimentID` = @currentID;
SELECT @currentID
```

But it still fails on that second line.

The full error message is:

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [MYSQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.9-log]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `Jobs_t` SET `JobStatus` = 'Pending' WHERE `ExperimentID = @currentID; S' at line 2

Comment: MySQL does not support bracketed `[]` identifiers (used by MS databases). Instead you must use backticks as `UPDATE \`Jobs_t\`...` or leave it unquoted because it isn't a keyword.

Comment: Just a thought...  Try changing [Jobs_t] to `Jobs_t`.

Comment: Are you actually using MySQL as your RDBMS? The way you identified your error makes me suspicious that this was actually intended for MySQL. , though we have superficially identified problems based on how you tagged it. Please post the full _exact_ error message and also verify that you are indeed using MySQL.

Comment: I am using MySQL. I've updated the OP with the exact error statement. The driver is `5.3a ANSI`, accessing MySQL via the System.Data.Odbc .NET class, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this as an answer.  Change

```
[Jobs_t]
```

to

```
`Jobs_t`
```

The character below the ~ on the top left of your keyboard.  Change that for all instances of your brackets.

Comment: I changed them all, still getting this error. The OP has more info.

Comment: Judging by what you added in there it looks like your variables are wrong.  @variable is normally used in SQL, with like Stored Procedures.  MySQL is usually executed via PHP, which would use $variable instead.

Comment: I ended up messing with the DSN settings in my ODBC editor. I had to tick "Allow multiple statements". Thanks for the syntax correction though! The error message just ended up being the wrong thing.